# Clip videoview within the bounds of a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a DialogFragment containing VideoViews. The issue is that once I start swiping left/right the VideoView is visible outside the boundaries of the ViewPager. How should I eliminate this. The rest of the controls on the page are ok and hide once I swipe away the page, only the VideoView remains visible.
I am testing on Android 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, try adding an invisible view above your VideoView. This worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- This transparent view avoids the videoview to be visible out of its bounds -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#0000" />

</FrameLayout>
```